# Get xml attribute value from an associated attribute value

Tags: c#, xml, linq, lambda

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33203110/how-can-i-use-an-xml-attribute-value-to-get-an-associated-element) question I found out how to use

```
XDocument MyData = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);
string color = MyData.Descendants("Red").Elements("Shade")
                     .Where(y => (int)y.Attribute("id") == 3).FirstOrDefault().Value;
```

to get an element by specifying an attribute "id". The above returns "lava" from the Xml below.

```
 <colours>
<Red>
<Shade id="1">
 <colour>crimson</colour>
 </Shade>
<Shade id="2">
 <colour>raspberry</colour>
 </Shade>
<Shade id="3">
 <colour>lava</colour>
 </Shade>
<Shade id="4">
 <colour>scarlet</colour>
 </Shade>
 </Red>
<Green>
<Shade id="1">
 <colour>asparagus</colour>
 </Shade>
<Shade id="2">
 <colour>emerald</colour>
 </Shade>
<Shade id="3">
 <colour>lime</colour>
 </Shade>
<Shade id="4">
 <colour>avocado</colour>
 </Shade>
 </Green>
<Blue>
<Shade id="1">
 <colour>cyan</colour>
 </Shade>
<Shade id="2">
 <colour>sapphire</colour>
 </Shade>
<Shade id="3">
 <colour>powder</colour>
 </Shade>
<Shade id="4">
 <colour>iris</colour>
 </Shade>
 </Blue>
 </colours>
```

In the following example my Shade elements have an extra attribute called 'group' (I've only added them to 'Red' for the sake of keeping it short. I need to do something similar to the previous, only this time instead of searching on an 'id' and returning its 'colour', I want to search on an 'id' and return its 'group' value.

One solution would be to change 'group' from an attribute to an element, which make adapting the Linq to Xml above more straightforward but I'm eager to see what a solution for the existing Xml would look like.

I'm also eager to learn more about Linq to Xml and using Lambda expressions like this. Any good learning resources you can point me towards will be very gratefully received.

```
 <colours>
<Red>
<Shade id="1" group="yes">
 <colour>crimson</colour>
 </Shade>
<Shade id="2" group="no">
 <colour>raspberry</colour>
 </Shade>
<Shade id="3" group="yes">
 <colour>lava</colour>
 </Shade>
<Shade id="4" group="no">
 <colour>scarlet</colour>
 </Shade>
 </Red>
<Green>
<Shade id="1">
 <colour>asparagus</colour>
 </Shade>
<Shade id="2">
 <colour>emerald</colour>
 </Shade>
<Shade id="3">
 <colour>lime</colour>
 </Shade>
<Shade id="4">
 <colour>avocado</colour>
 </Shade>
 </Green>
<Blue>
<Shade id="1">
 <colour>cyan</colour>
 </Shade>
<Shade id="2">
 <colour>sapphire</colour>
 </Shade>
<Shade id="3">
 <colour>powder</colour>
 </Shade>
<Shade id="4">
 <colour>iris</colour>
 </Shade>
 </Blue>
 </colours>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
string color = MyData.Descendants("Red").Elements("Shade").Where(y => (int)y.Attribute("id") == 3).FirstOrDefault().Attribute("group");
```

Comment: using

    var color = ... etc

then referring to 

    color.Value

worked!

Lovely, thank you.

Comment: @PaulRathbone - If the answer helped you, you should thank by upvoting \ accepting the answer. This is how this community works. Check this - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up Rahul. Until this moment I had less than 15 experience points so I was unable to upvote.

Answer (score 2):

Since `group` is an attribute, you can use `.Attribute` method like this:-

```
var colors = MyData.Root.Element("Red")
                        .Elements("Shade")
                        .FirstOrDefault(y => (int)y.Attribute("id") == 3);
string group;
if (colors != null)
        group = (string)colors.Attribute("group");
```

**Description:**

We need to start from root node so `MyData.Root` will give `colours` which is the root node, then we need to pick the `Red` element because we don't have multiple `Red` node so it makes no sense to use `Descendants` here. Now inside `Red` node we can use `Elements` method to fetch all `Shade` nodes. (Why we are not using `Descendants` here? Check [difference between them](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3705042/1529657).) Finally we are using `FirstOrDefault` method to fetch the first node having `id` attribute as `3`. It will return `null` if no node satisfies the condition, this is the reason we are first checking if it is returning null only then fetching the `group` attribute otherwise it will throw Null reference exception.